# SQL Server stored procedure creates same sequence number file with different date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, ssis

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that's part of an SSIS package which generates a `.txt` file each day with a different sequence number. For example
FileName01**30**2018**514** and next day it would be FileName01**31**2018**515**...

The HeaderNumber in the stored procedure generates the file ending sequence number like 514, 515, 516...

My issue: when there is no data for the day the file is generated like FileName01**30**2018**514** with zero records. And next day when we have data the file is generated like FieName01**31**2018**514**. Notice the ending numbers are the same "514." But it should be ending in 515 for next day.

How can I modify the stored procedure so each day it produces a different ending sequence number like 514, 515, 516?

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [outboundprocess].[usp_BdsExportStatusUpdate]
     @vFileName VARCHAR(500), 
     -- @[User::vFileName]  --default for testing
     @HeaderNumber VARCHAR(250) OUTPUT,
     @HeaderFooter VARCHAR(250) OUTPUT
 AS
 BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON

     DECLARE @sDatetime VARCHAR(50),
             @ModifiedDate DATETIME = GETDATE(),
             @iFileCounter INTEGER,
             @sFileCounter VARCHAR(50) 

     DECLARE @ErrCode INT, @ErrDesc VARCHAR(8000)   

     BEGIN TRY
         SET @iFileCounter = (SELECT MAX(ISNULL(HeaderNumber, 0)) 
                              FROM solix.BdsLog) + 1
         IF @iFileCounter > 999 
         BEGIN
             UPDATE solix.BdsLog 
             SET HeaderNumber = 0

             SET @iFileCounter = 1
         END    

         SET @sFileCounter = FORMAT(@iFileCounter, '000') -- SELECT @sFileCounter

         UPDATE dbo.Customers 
         SET ModifiedBy = 'BDSExport.dtsx',
             ModifiedDate = @ModifiedDate,
             BDSFileStatus = CASE 
                                WHEN C.StatusID = 130 
                                   THEN 'D' 
                                   ELSE 'S' 
                             END  --means sent to BDS,
         FROM dbo.Customers C 
         INNER JOIN Solix.BdsLog B ON LEFT( C.AccountNumber, 10) = B.AccountNumberL10
                                   AND B.CustCreateDate = C.CreateDate
         WHERE BdsSubmitStatus = 'ReadyToSend' 

         UPDATE Solix.BdsLog
         SET ModifiedBy = 'BDSExport.dtsx',
             ModifiedDate = @ModifiedDate,
             BdsSubmitStatus = 'Sended',
             BdsExportFileName = @vFileName,
             HeaderNumber = @iFileCounter
         WHERE 
             BdsSubmitStatus = 'ReadyToSend' 

         DECLARE @sHeaderNumber VARCHAR(250),
                 @sFooterNumber VARCHAR(250),
                 @iRecordCounter INTEGER,
                 @sRecordCounter VARCHAR(50)  


SET @iRecordCounter=(SELECT COUNT( Solix.BdsLog.BdsLogIdentity) FROM  
Solix.BdsLog WHERE ModifiedDate=@ModifiedDate AND 
BdsExportFileName=@vFileName)
SET @sRecordCounter=FORMAT(@iRecordCounter,'000000000') --SELECT 
@sRecordCounter

SET @sDatetime = FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyyMMddHHmm') -- SELECT @sDatetime

SET @sHeaderNumber=@sDatetime+'SOLIX ' +'TJRL11'+ @sFileCounter
SET @sFooterNumber=@sHeaderNumber

SET @sHeaderNumber='M$9001'+@sHeaderNumber+ REPLICATE(' ',36)+'2'
SET @sFooterNumber='M$9002'+@sFooterNumber+ REPLICATE(' 
',15)+ISNULL(@sRecordCounter,0)+ REPLICATE(' ',12)+'2'

--OUTPUT--------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------
SET @HeaderNumber=@sHeaderNumber
SET @HeaderFooter=@sFooterNumber 

END TRY

===========================================================
--CATCH Errors
--================================================================
BEGIN CATCH         
    DECLARE @ErrorNumber INT,
            @ErrorSeverity INT,             
            @ErrorState INT,            
            @ErrorProcedure VARCHAR(8000),
            @ErrorLine INT,                     
            @ErrorMessage VARCHAR(8000)

    SELECT
        @ErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER(),
        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE(),
        @ErrorProcedure = ERROR_PROCEDURE(),
        @ErrorLine = ERROR_LINE(),
        @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()

        SET @ErrCode = @ErrorNumber  
        SET @ErrDesc = @ErrorMessage  

        SELECT @ErrDesc 


END CATCH       

END
```

Comment: @vFileName this is a variable passed from the previous process.. question is how did you pass the value to this variable?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu when updating Solix.bdslog table 
    BdsExportFileName=@vFileName,

Comment: i suppose you should post that not this proc

Comment: @maSTAShuFu this update is in this proc. If you see where it says update Solix.Bdslog you will see BdsExportFileName=@vFileName

Comment: If you're able to use the `FORMAT` statement in your T-SQL code, I suspect you're *not* running against 2008 anymore, but against at least 2012 or newer. Those versions also support **sequence** objects to handle this very task - handing out consecutive numbers. Check them out! Would be **much easier** and safer than rolling your own!!

Answer (score 0):

The number is stored in @iFileCounter and stored in HeaderNumber column in Solix.BdsLog. It get updated by this statement

```
UPDATE       Solix.BdsLog
SET     
    ModifiedBy='BDSExport.dtsx',
    ModifiedDate=@ModifiedDate,
    BdsSubmitStatus = 'Sended',
    BdsExportFileName=@vFileName,
    HeaderNumber=@iFileCounter
    WHERE BdsSubmitStatus='ReadyToSend'
```

Because of the where clause, this update only occurs when the BdsSubmitStatus is "ReadyToSend", which is must not be if the file is empty. You need to update the log (or at least the HeaderNumber) even if the file was not sent. You probably need to modify the BdsSubmitStatus in that case as well. Something like this should work

```
UPDATE       Solix.BdsLog
SET     
    ModifiedBy='BDSExport.dtsx',
    ModifiedDate=@ModifiedDate,
    BdsSubmitStatus = CASE WHEN BdsSubmitStatus='ReadyToSend' THEN'Sended' ELSE 'FileEmpty' END,
    BdsExportFileName=@vFileName,
    HeaderNumber=@iFileCounter
    WHERE BdsSubmitStatus IN ('ReadyToSend', 'EmptyFileStatusHere')
```

You will need to figure out and set the right empty file status in the where clause, or you could just remove the WHERE clause entirely, if there are no other states to worry about.

You should make sure that there is no other process that reads this log file to control a process, and that will break if you update the number and there is no file present.

Answer (score 0):

Set a start date , and find the date difference with the current date.
Then you can get the unique increment number.

For example, if you have started this process yesterday , then hard code that date as a start date, and find the date difference with current date.

```
Declare @start_date Date, @inc_no int
Set @start_date = '30-Jan-2018'
Set @inc_no = DATEDIFF(day,@start_date,convert(date,getdate()))
print @inc_no
```

And then append the @inc_no with your file name.